# Return records in SQL that include all values from IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exists

Apologies if the title is not completely accurate, but I am not sure how to phrase my question exactly. I would like to return only rows where the results include all items in the IN statement grouped on particular columns. So my query is:

```
    SELECT [DRSY],
           [DRRT],
           [DRKY],
           [DRDL01]
      FROM dbo.f0005
     WHERE DRKY IN ('FC', 'OO', 'SH')
```

I want to return records where DRSY and DRRT include all of the items 'FC', 'OO', 'SH'. Perhaps a picture will help illustrate this:

[image: Results where DRSY = 00 and DRRT = DT]

The only rows I want returned are where DRSY = '00' and DRRT = 'DT' because this includes all 3 values I specified. I have tried searching for different ways to use IN, EXISTS, and even ALL.

Comment: can you not specify them in the WHERE clause? WHERE DRSY = '00' and DRRT = 'DT'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is the order important, is the first value always `DRSY` and the second `DRRT` etc?

Comment: That is just one example. I want to be able to determine all groupings of columns DRSY and DRRT values that have all values in the where clause. There could also be a combination of DRSY = '01' and DRRT = 'ST' that also have all 3 values. This is what I am trying to find.

Comment: Ah sorry, SQL Server 2012.

Comment: But `DRSY` and `DRRT` are only two columns. How can they contain all three values? Also, why  does _`DRSY = '00'` and `DRRT = 'DT'`  include all 3 values  specified_? The values are `'FC', 'OO', 'SH'`

Comment: Yes Tim, that is the order. The codes in `DRKY` are all grouped by a combination of columns `DRSY` (first) and `DRRT` (second). `DRKY` contains a set of user-defined valid values, so each set of values is indicated by columns `DRSY` and `DRRT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this can be done by GROUPING and then ensuring the DISTINCT count is equal to the number of search items:

```
   SELECT [DRSY],
          [DRRT]
   FROM dbo.f0005
   WHERE DRKY IN ('FC', 'OO', 'SH')
   GROUP BY [DRSY], [DRRT]
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DRKY) = 3;
```

**Edit, Re Ensuring Count of Items remains in Sync**

What you could do is build up a derived table or CTE containing the list of desired values (`searchValues`), which you can then join to (instead of `IN`) and then you will be able to `COUNT` the `searchValues` to avodi any maintenance issues with counting values.

```
WITH searchValues AS
(
    select val 
    from (values ('FC'), ('OO'), ('SH')) as s(val)
)
SELECT [DRSY],
       [DRRT]
   FROM dbo.f0005
   INNER JOIN searchValues s
   ON DRKY = s.val
   GROUP BY [DRSY], [DRRT]
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DRKY) = (SELECT COUNT(val) FROM searchValues);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58701/4)

Comment: This is good - I just have to increase the number in the having clause if I add another value to the IN clause. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewCorson actually, what you could do is build up a table, cte or derived table containing the 'search' values and this way improve the maintainability of the query - I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT DRSY, DRRT, DRKY, DRDL01 FROM dbo.f0005 a
WHERE exists (
   SELECT * FROM dbo.f005 b WHERE DRKY = "FC" and a.DRSY = b.DRSY and a.DRRT = b.DRRT
)
AND exists (
   SELECT * FROM dbo.f005 c WHERE DRKY = "00" and a.DRSY = c.DRSY and a.DRRT = c.DRRT
)
AND exists (
   SELECT * FROM dbo.f005 d WHERE DRKY = "SH" and a.DRSY = d.DRSY and a.DRRT = d.DRRT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @StuartLC's example and changed it a bit. This way I am able to include other columns from the table as well. Thanks again Stuart!

```
    WITH drky_count
    AS (SELECT DR.DRSY,
               DR.DRRT,
               DR.DRKY,
               DR.DRDL01,
               COUNT (DR.DRKY) OVER (PARTITION BY DR.DRSY, DR.DRRT)
                  AS DRKY_COUNT
          FROM f0005 DR
         WHERE DR.DRKY IN ('FC', 'OO', 'SH'))
    SELECT  DRSY, DRRT, DRKY, DRDL01
      FROM drky_count
     WHERE DRKY_COUNT = (SELECT MAX (DRKY_COUNT) FROM drky_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
SELECT [DRSY], [DRRT] FROM dbo.f0005 WHERE DRKY = 'FC'
INTERSECT
SELECT [DRSY], [DRRT] FROM dbo.f0005 WHERE DRKY = 'OO'
INTERSECT
SELECT [DRSY], [DRRT] FROM dbo.f0005 WHERE DRKY = 'SH'
```